# BUILD FAILED to flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I was not getting this error before, but now I am getting this error. Can you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yoqI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project path includes "ü" character so there is this problem. I think you should change your project path that doesnt includes "ü,ş,ı,ö,ç,ğ".